# store images in iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I am simply creating a student management system in iPhone.

There I need to store student's small images,

Which should be appear in tableView,

Ok, I know how to work with tableView...
how to work with database...

But question is

Where to store images
how can we obtain the path of stored images..

Do i have to store entire images to database...

Or

i have to store relative path of image to database...

What is suggested by You masters?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create image files on the file system of the device in the Document directory. Use something like this:

```
// Generate a unique user filename
NSString *imageFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"student_image_%@", uniqueIdentifier];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], imageFilename];

NSData *storage = [image UIImagePNGRepresentation]; // or UIImageJPEGRepresentation

[storage writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

Best Regards,

Comment: Thank you very much....This is working fine...But can you tell me how can I get the path if once i have stored this image a file now i want to retrive that image then how it can be possible ?